# Angular 2 JIT Compiler very strange behavior

Tags: angular, angular2-compiler

I recently updated from angular 2.3.1 to 2.4.7, and I've found a very strange behavior, That's the code:

UpcomingGames.html

```
<div class="row nomargin upcomingGames">
    <tl-responsive-height [margin]="15">
            <tl-upcoming-game *ngFor="let game of gamesSubscription |async"
                              [game]="game"
                              color="#8777b4"></tl-upcoming-game>
    </tl-responsive-height>
</div>
```

ResponsiveHeight.html template:

```
<div class="scrollable"
     #scrollable
     (scroll)="moveScrollbar()">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<div class="scroll-rail" #scrollbar
    (mousedown)="drag($event)"
></div>
```

If I run `ng server` in angular 2.3.1 and `ng server --aot`in 2.4.7 everything works properly, but in 2.4.7 with JIT compiler, the div with class scrollable is propagated inside every upcoming-game in the ngFor.

I think this can be understood with a couple of images.

This is the correct behavior:
[image]

And this is the weird behavior:
[image]

As you can see, responsive height template is duplicated inside upcoming-game template.

Like I said, this doesn't happen with AOT in 2.4.7 or JIT in 2.3.1.

I have another pages in the app and all work properly except this one.
I use responsiveHeight component in another components that the router is not involved in and works everything.

I would say it's related with Router + component transclusion + ngFor.

Versions:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.31
node: 6.9.1
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.7
@angular/compiler: 2.4.7
@angular/core: 2.4.7
@angular/forms: 2.4.7
@angular/http: 2.4.7
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.7
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.7
@angular/router: 3.4.7
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.31
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.7
```

**UPDATE:**

If I remove ngFor works properly.
If I remove async pipe and fill ngFor with sync data, doesn't work.

**UPDATE2:**

If I create a noop component that transcludes the content, everything works:

```
<div class="row nomargin upcomingGames">
  <noop-transclusion>
    <tl-responsive-height [margin]="15">
            <tl-upcoming-game *ngFor="let game of gamesSubscription |async"
                              [game]="game"
                              color="#8777b4"></tl-upcoming-game>
    </tl-responsive-height>
  </noop-transclusion>
</div>
```

It seems ngFor is related to this.